# How to remove the Port number from my url?

Tags: tomcat6

I am using Apache Tomcat6.0.i am relatively new to servers.i want to remove my port number from my URL.i searched for the listening port it is "wampapache". 
Example:

```
     localhost:8080/myappname/ (it is like this)

     localhost/myappname(my requirement)
```

P.s :- i searched for my answer and found i have to change  to  i did this and it says" some other service is running in this port so please stop those services or change port number!!! ".if anyone can guide me it would be helpful.

Thnaks in Adv!!

Comment: In general, only one service (process) can have a port open at a time. Is there something else listening on port 80? Or have you even tried changing the Tomcat configuration to set the port to 80 (the standard HTTP port)?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart :wampapache is listening in that port and when I try to stop it  is throwing an error that access denied!!!

Comment: Are you doing so as root?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart thanks for  the suggestion . Its working now.Had to stop some service!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Found the Pid From console and then Stopped the listening service by going to services.msc!

1)Open Cmd as administrator(right click and you can find the option).

2)type "netstat -ano" in the console

3)Find the services running on my required port "80"(here 80 because I don't want the port number to be displayed in the URL).note the PID number.

4)Open Task Manager then , click on services tab. Find the service name of the PID.

5)Type "services.msc" in Run. there find the Service name  and right click and disable the service.

Comment: Elaborate on the answer so future visitors understand what you had to do